# How i can group my @Html.RadioButtonFor according to the Item foreign key value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button, html-helper

I have 2 models inside my asp.net mvc-5 web application:-

```
public partial class Anwer
    {
        public Anwer()
        {
            this.UserFormsAnswers = new HashSet<UserFormsAnswer>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AnwerDesc { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public bool Correct { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserFormsAnswer> UserFormsAnswers { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.Anwers = new HashSet<Anwer>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDesc { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Anwer> Anwers { get; set; }
    }
```

now i want to show all the questions inside the view and for each question to show its answers in a radio buttons, so i tried the following:-

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionsDemo.Models.Question>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @{int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in Model)
{
                <div class="form-group">
                    @(i+1) <spn>-</spn> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionDesc) <br />
                    @foreach (var answer in item.Anwers)
        {
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelitem2 => answer.QuestionID, answer.Id) @answer.AnwerDesc  <br /> 
                        </div>
        }
                </div><hr/>
}

        }
    </div>
}
```

I thought that all the answers' radio buttons for a question will have the same name. so users can only select one option for each question. but seems all the answers radio-buttons got the same name as follow:-

```
<input id="answer_QuestionID" name="answer.QuestionID" type="radio" value="1" /> 10  <br />
```

so can any one adivce on this ? how i can group the radio buttons per question?

second question. how i can post back all the answers ids to my post action method? should i use indexer ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate the form controls for `Question`. You need to use a `for` loop, or better a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Question`. Refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for a detailed explanation.

Your `Question` model also needs a property to bind the selected `Answer` to, for example

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

And note that your editing data so you should be creating view models for both `Question` and `Answer`, not using data models in your view.

Create a partial view `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/QuestionVM.cshtml` with the following code

```
@model QuestionsDemo.Models.Question

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
// Add additional hidden inputs for any properties of Question that you want to be posted
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.QuestionDesc)
@foreach(var answer in Model.Anwers)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, answer.Id, new { id = "" })
        <span>@answer.AnwerDesc</span>
    </label>
}
```

Then the main view will be

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionsDemo.Models.Question>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Note the `EditorFor()` method will correctly generate the html for each item in the collection.

Comment: now it worked well in respect to the radio buttons and how they are being rendered.. but inside my action method i wrote the following `public async Task<ActionResult> Create(List<int> SelectedAnswer)` to capture the selected radio buttons.. Now the SelectedAnswer list will have the correct number of items,, but the value for all the items will be zero instead of having the answerid ??

Comment: can you adivce on my above comment please?

Comment: The model in the view is `IEnumerable<Question>`, therefore you POST method must match - `public ActionResult XXX (IEnumerable<Question> model)` and `model` will contain all the information you have submitted. And having `List<int> SelectedAnswer` would make no sense - it does not contain the data about the question that the answer relates to :)

Comment: now i find this problem ,, not sure how i can fix it.. now if the view is rendered after a model state error the view will be empty.. so seems  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` will not get rendered in-case the view is rendered again due to model state errors ?? my post action method will have the following :- `public async Task<ActionResult> Create(IEnumerable<Question> Question) { if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {}return View(Question);}`

Comment: so i am not sur if i can post back the answers info insdie the partial view,, when the view is rendered after a model state error..

Comment: Yes of course you can. I assume you mean that the `QuestionDesc` and `AnwerDesc` values are not displayed when you return the view which would be because you did not include hidden inputs for them in the view so they are not sent to the server. Either include the inputs or get that data again from the database.

Comment: but one last question i can not understand how the code you provided worked internally ??.. as inside the main view i will be passing `IEnumerable<QuestionsDemo.Models.Question>` while in the partial view it will be accepting single `Question` object. so when i define `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` i though this will raise an exception since the partial view is defined to accept a single Question object,, while i will be passing `IEnumerable<QuestionsDemo.Models.Question>` .. but i did not get any exception...

Comment: Because the `EditorFor()` method has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`. If you pass `IEnumerable<T>` then the method will internally loop through the collection and use the `EditorTemplate` to generate the correct html for each item